# Extrating data from jsp form to controller and saving them to database

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Hello I am trying to save data from a form to database however I have no idea how to continue now. I have this following code.

I tried using the `request.getParameter("id")` in the controller which gave me an compiler error.

So how do I get the data from the jsp form to the controller and then save them to the MySQL database ?

jsp file

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="ProductController" method="post">
        <p>Enter product name :</p> <input id="productName" type="text" name="username"> <BR>
        <p>Enter product serial number :</p> <input id="serialNumber" type="password" name="password"> <BR>
        <input type="submit" placeholder="Submit" />
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

The controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/product")
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public ModelAndView list() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("product/list");
        System.out.println("Count:" + productService.getProducts().size());
        modelAndView.addObject("test", "mytest");
        modelAndView.addObject("count", productService.getProducts().size());
        modelAndView.addObject("products", productService.getProducts());
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

and product DAO

```
@Override
public void saveProduct(Product product) {
    //persist(product);

    Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.persist(product);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What is your question, _specifically_?

Comment: Well the problem is me not knowing how to implement the insert...I have figured out how to save the product to the database but now I need to extract it from the form and use to controller and that is where I am stuck. I dont know how to proceed further.

Comment: That's is a statement. What is your question? If you question is: "How to save?", that is unclear and too broad. Clarify exactly where the problem is, what you've tried, why you tried that, what did you expect, why did you expect that, what actually happened, why it didn't work.

Comment: I tried writing a method in the controller which had mapping set to the add.jsp file and I tried the `request.getParameter("id")` which gave me an compiler error. So my question is how do I get the parameters from the form to the controller and how do I pass them further to the DAO?

Comment: Please update your question accordingly with the clarifications requested.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use name attribute of html element to get value, like request.getParameter("username");